# How to interchange keys and values in a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to interchange keys and value in a given dictionary. For example:

```
dict = {1:'sandeep', 2: 'suresh', 3: 'pankaj'}
```

will become:

```
dict1 = {'sandeep': 1, 'suresh': 2, 'pankaj': 3}
```

Comment: `{val: key for key, val in dict.items()}`? But you shouldn't name your own dictionary `dict`, and will you **always** have unique, hashable values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `zip` is probably better than a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict1 = dict(zip(dict1.values(), dict1.keys())) # better for beginners
```

Comment: Make sure your original dictionary is `dict1` instead of `dict`.

Comment: Beginners aren't too familiar with comprehensions in general, but most are familiar with some of the built-in methods.

Comment: I don't think you should make that assumption. And even if true, beginners ought to become familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [45]: d = {1:'sandeep',2 : 'suresh', 3: 'pankaj'}

In [46]: {(v, k) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
Out[46]: {'pankaj': 3, 'sandeep': 1, 'suresh': 2}
```

Note the use of `d` as the variable name instead of the built-in `dict`.

Also note that you are not guaranteed uniqueness and can loose entries:

```
In [47]: d = {1:'sandeep',2 : 'suresh', 3: 'pankaj', 4:'suresh'}

In [48]: {(v, k) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
Out[48]: {'pankaj': 3, 'sandeep': 1, 'suresh': 4}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a dictionary comprehension directly? `{v: k for k,v in d.iteritems()}`

Comment: @MJeffryes Yes, you are right, much better this way. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: According to the tag "**python-3.x**" `iteritems` should be replaced by `items`.